# Dependency injection alternatives to Unity.Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been using Unity.Mvc3 as my dependency injection mechanism.

What are the alternatives available?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using [autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) . However I know lots of people are using StructureMap and lots prefer Ninject. Afaik, though autofac has the best performance (followed by StructureMap)

Comment: Thanks Mike. Is Autofac easy to set up?

Comment: Of course, it's basically the same as with unity. Nuget the packages then set the dependecy resolver

Comment: Thanks again Mike, I will definitely check that package out.